# HTML/Jscript/Contact Form 7: Easiest way to hide several labels at once

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following piece of code i'm working on, I want to find an easy way to hide all the labels after (and including) Text2 whenever Option1 or Option2 are selected on the drop menu. I tried working around with class elements but they seem to break my script, right now I am only able to hide one label only (text5). Would you mind helping me?

```
<p><label>Text1</label> [select* id:mobileProvider "Option1" "Option2"</p>
<p><label>Text2</label></p>
<p><label>Text3</label></p>
<p><label>Text4</label></p>
<p><label id="sub">Text5</label></p>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("mobileProvider").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);

  function displayTextField() {
    var dropDownText = document.getElementById("mobileProvider").value;
    if (dropDownText == "Option1") {
      document.getElementById("sub").style.display = 'none';
    } else if (dropDownText == "Option2") {
      document.getElementById("sub").style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("sub").style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please use the snippet tool `<>` in the editor to create a [mcve].

Comment: Changed it a little, although it's shitty of you to thumb it down because of it, the code wasn't that complicated.

Comment: What kind of value does `document.getElementsByClass("hid").style.display` return?

Comment: An array of display tags?

Comment: No. Try using the browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: Should I use the console for it, and make it into a proper function, or is there some way to run this singular command?

Comment: I made some new changes (look at the original question), but it still doesn't work. All paragraphs are still visible.

Comment: Try [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?kae=d&kz=-1&kn=1&kg=p&q=mdn%20command%20line%20interpreter)ing. Using the snippet tool to create a [mcve] (as stated above) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) can also be helpful. [Learn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the 'class' tag in every paragraph to 'hid' and added the next row in my script, and it did the trick.

```
var hide = document.getElementsByClassName('hid'),i = hide.length;
while(i--) { 
    hide[i].style.display= 'none'; }
```